# Elasticsearch with request body results in all documents

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I followed the tutorial on ElasticSearch's website for uploading documents(John smith, Jane Smith etc). When I'm querying the index using URI search the results are relevant. But when using request body for any kind of match query,it returns all the documents with _score for each set as 1 i.e. without any relevance. Please help.

```
$ curl -XGET localhost:9200/megacorp/employee/_search {"query":{"match":
```

Comment: You question is incomplete, there is a part of your request that we cannot see. Can you finish the query in your question?

Answer (score 0):

I need to see the complete request in order to fully understand your problem, but it seems that you are using GET as the method in the request.

In order to make a proper request with a body to ElasticSearch the method should be **POST** (you are using **GET**)